# upgrade package without removing changes to file

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm still fairly new to npm so I don't know if this is possible or not, But if I decide to upgrade a package, but I've altered one of the files inside the package, is there a way to still upgrade everything else but keep my changes in the affected files?

For example, I've pulled in the aurelia-validation package and I've altered some of the string resources in resources/en-EN.js. Can I upgrade the aurelia-validation package and pull in any new additions to that file without removing the ones I've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to exclude specific changes, but perhaps there is a way to exclude specific files from upgrading.

Either way, it is **very unrecommended** to make changes in 3rd party libraries.
Instead you can overwrite specific functions or global variables from outside the package.

So for example you have a package and wish to change a function in there, currently you have:

```
var aurelia = require('aurelia-validation');
aurelia.someFunction();
```

you should overwrite it in a seperate file like this:

**aurelia-validaiton-overwrite.js**

```
aurelia.someFunction = function() {
    // new implementation
};
```

and require it afterwards like this:

```
var aurelia = require('aurelia-validation');
var aurelia = require('aurelia-validation-overwrite.js');
```

Then you can safely NPM-update, but you'll have to make sure your changes are working well with the new version of that library.